# Uploading using Filepond library

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, uploading, filepond

please after previewing i cant seem to get my choosed files in preview to be sent via the FILES header in php once i submit the form generally ...

this is the html

```
<div class="col-md-7">
<div class="md-form p-2 border rounded">
    <input type="file" name="images[]" id="more_images" class="my-pond-multiple" />
    <label for="files" class="active bg-white ml-2">Other Files</label>
</div>
```

and the me calling the file pond jquery object

```
$('.my-pond-multiple').filepond({
    allowMultiple: true
});
```

any help will be appreciated please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FilePond files are not stored in the file input element, browsers don't allow setting this value (see: https://pqina.nl/blog/the-trouble-with-editing-and-uploading-files-in-the-browser/)

You can either upload the files asynchronously by setting the FilePond `server` property. Or you can use the [FilePond file-encode plugin](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/file-encode/), which will encode the files as base64 strings and send those to your server, you then have to turn the strings back into file objects.

Comment: thanks a lot found this out .... also got a way to get the file and use it synchronously instead or async

Comment: Hi, I'm uploading files via filepond to the server which is working fine, how do I get the filenames of files that uploaded when submitting the form for processing ?